# Alignment of Buttons with AdView

Tags: android, alignment, adview

I have a Layout for Android app with few buttons in it. I am trying to set an Ad at the bottom of the page. Please refer to my layout below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_color"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_top_margin" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/nav_text_size" >
            </TextView>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ProceedToScreen31"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_name"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/TA1"
                android:textColor="@color/btn_text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ProceedToScreen32"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_name"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/TA2"
                android:textColor="@color/btn_text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ProceedToScreen33"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_name"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/TA3"
                android:textColor="@color/btn_text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ProceedToScreen34"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_name"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/TA4"
                android:textColor="@color/btn_text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size" >
            </Button>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:background="@color/line_color" >
            </View>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/copyright"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Ad is perfectly coming to the bottom of the page as fixed footer (As per my requirement) but along with that other components of the page are also coming to the bottom of the page leaving, big space at the top of the page. PLease help How can I align so that Only Ad should come to the bottom of the page, rest all components should start from the top of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for your inputs, there was problem with my code, I was setting Ad with Java class as well as in the XML file both places, I removed the Ad code in Java and changed little bit of code in XML file as per suggestions here  android:layout_above="@+id/adView"

Now everything looks fine and as per requirement. Thanks again for your time and inputs.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of this line in the scroll view:

`android:layout_above="@+id/adView"`

It's doing that because you're basically telling it, "*Just* above the adView, put the ScrollView." Just removing that fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of that but without layout_above, the last few lines of the page are hidden by the Ad that's why I added layout_above. That's if I have lot of content in the page, even after scrolling down to the page, I am unable to see last couple of lines, which are hidden by Ad Banner.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

from the top layout. Actually, I would remove all references to gravity until you have things in the right place, personally. Also, you might want to check how large

```
@dimen/activity_top_margin
```

is. It may well explain the space you have.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but that didn't help. also @dimen/activity_top_margin is just 16dp.

Comment: Could you post some pictures (say one for each case you mention) and add links to them to the question, I'm not sure I understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the `ScrollView` -> `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and this will remove the blank space on the top.

In addition, I would suggest to set the `AdView` first and then set the `ScrollView` with `android:layout_above="@+id/adView"` because `ScrollView` sets its layout accordingly to the `AdView` and sometimes it is required to define first the layout that doesn't relies on any other layout and then define other layouts.